# wkhtmltopdf not properly rendering page having dojo

Tags: dojo, wkhtmltopdf

> Hi everyone, I want to convert a html page into pdf. my code is
>   working fine but is not giving desired output while trying to convert
>   page having dojo implemented.

Answer (score -2):

What does "not giving desired output" mean?

Also, you mention using Dojo. You realise that Javascript-based content will not be in the PDF?

Comment: with "not giving desired output" i wanted to say,what i am getting in the pdf is not what i can see in the web browser when i load that page.

Comment: So you give a downvote and don't answer the other more crucial part of the question?

Comment: i had not given down vote and i know java script contents are not displayed in the pdf. But, in my case other contents are also not their in the pdf.

Comment: wkhtmltopdf can do JavaScript: `wkhtmltopdf-amd64 --enable-javascript --javascript-delay 2000` For example, I have a website using the OpenLayers JavaScript mapping library to display a map using JavaScript. This is included in the PDF correctly. However, if I include some Dojo-1.7 AMD-style functions in the Javascript wkhtmltopdf does not run them, even though it is running the non-AMD OpenLayers JavaScript correctly